# Websites about past and future missions

Tags: launch, rockets

What are some good space related websites (or other resources) that have information about past and future missions?

I'm looking for data such as mission launch date, type of rocket, launch site, type of mission (manned/unmanned) etc.

Comment: Related on meta: http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/questions/600/is-there-value-in-questions-about-future-schedules

Comment: Related on meta: http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/questions/795/should-we-edit-a-date-into-questions-that-are-moving-targets

Comment: Lists of launches can be found on Wikipedia for many programs.

Comment: Seconding wikipedia; surprisingly good for basic information of the type you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Past missions: http://www.spacelaunchreport.com/
Launch schedule: https://spaceflightnow.com/launch-schedule/

Answer (score 1):

You can also check out Blastoff, which allows you to filter upcoming launches by their launch location. It's just a cheap layer that I programmed on-top of the excellent launchlibrary.net API.

Url: http://mrhuffman.net/projects/blastoff